NavigationStack clipping contents of .toolbar modifier
When using a custom .toolbar within a NavigationStack, the contents of the toolbar are getting clipped on navigation-pop. The code below first renders the view as expected (without any clipping). But as soon as a new destination is pushed onto the stack, and then popped back via the built-in Back action, the clipping occurs. Everything looks correct on initial load and during the nav transition, but when the transition is finished, the issue occurs.
I followed the official documentation to construct this hierarchy, but does anyone see anything obviously wrong with the code? Or is this a bug in SwiftUI?
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    @State var destinations: [Color] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $destinations) {
            Color.blue
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("First Line Title")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                            Text("Second Line Subtitle")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Color.self, destination: { color in
                    color
                })
                .onTapGesture {
                    destinations.append(.red)
                }
        }
    }
}

This is what it looks like in practice:

P.S.: I'm using iOS 17.2 as the deployment target.

You should not put large views like this in a navigation bar. You cannot control the size of the built-in navigation bar.
I would suggest doing .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) and writing your own navigation bar with .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) { ... } if you want it to have a custom appearance.
By inspecting the view hierarchy, the view is clipped because one of the subviews of the UINavigationBar has clipsToBounds = true. Therefore, as a hack, you can get access to the UINavigationBar with a UIViewControllerRepresentable, and never allow clipsToBounds to be set to true.
import Combine

struct NavBarNoClip: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
          ViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    }

    private class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            guard let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar, cancellables.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            for subview in navBar.subviews {
                subview.publisher(for: \.clipsToBounds).sink { clipped in
                    if clipped {
                        subview.clipsToBounds = false
                    }
                }
                .store(in: &cancellables)
            }
        }
    }
}

Then you can put .background { NavBarNoClip() } on the Color.blue or any view inside the NavigationStack.

Thanks, that works. Using the .safeAreaInset trick was actually my preferred/first approach, but it can't handle view transitions at all so when you navigate between views, you need to interpolate the changes yourself. To make matters worse, the back-swipe gesture seems to be governed by UINavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer. So the title interpolation would require a lot of hacking, if it's possible at all, since you'd need to somehow get your hands on the mutating content offset of the gesture, and you can only get to the starting location, as far as I'm aware.

Btw, this whole UIView[Controller]Representable approach seems like bad API design, and a kind of anti-pattern. We are forced to pollute our SwiftUI code with these UIKit hacks, and then put lipstick on them to make them look like regular view modifiers. In this case, if my design calls for a custom toolbar, and Apple allows me to create one natively, the expected behavior should match the rest of the framework. That is, views expand with content and shrink to bounds. I shouldn't need to filter on inner views each time I need to customize something. But patience is a virtue, they say...

FYI, I opened a ticket to Apple (FB14898777) so I'll chime in again if they update it.
